# String manipulation in R

Tags: r, string

I have a list of DNA sequences, for example, "AGAACCTTATTGGGTCAAGT".  If I were wanting to create a list with all possible strings that could sequentially happen in the sequence of a given length (for example 4) how would this be done in R?

In this case, the first string would be "AGAA".  The second would be "GAAC", the third, "AACC", and so forth.

Comment: Look up generating permutations.

Answer (score 3):

```
x = "AGAACCTTATTGGGTCAAGT"
sapply(1:(nchar(x)-3), function(i) substr(x, i, i+3))
#[1] "AGAA" "GAAC" "AACC" "ACCT" "CCTT" "CTTA" "TTAT" "TATT" "ATTG" "TTGG" "TGGG" "GGGT" "GGTC" "GTCA" "TCAA" "CAAG" "AAGT"
```

Comment: Thanks!  If the sequences were in a large list, would it be more efficient to first unlist and then use sapply or to use a for statement going through each list element?